# Removing a duplicate grub installation

Tags: grub2

I'd like to remove a (non functional) duplicate grub installation. I ended up with two different grub installations after copying a Kubuntu partition from another PC and trying to install grub manually. After hours of trying to make it work (couldn't get rid of "no such device" + "unknown filesystem" errors upon arriving on grub), I just gave up and reinstalled Kubuntu from scratch. So now I have this:

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0005,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Hard Drive
Boot0002* grub
Boot0005* ubuntu
```

Boot0002 grub is the faulty one. From what I've read I can remove it with `efibootmgr -Bb 0002` but I believe this only removes the boot entry and not the actual grub installation. How can I ensure grub is properly uninstalled before removing the corresponding entry?

**Edit**: I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader) but it requires Windows (I have a dual boot). Keeping this question open as someone might be interested in a linux-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you have unused/old kernel packages and this effectively removes also the grub entries and frees hard drive space. To do that you need to check what kernels are installed using:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

And then you can remove the unused/old kernel image if any exist using:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-version_number
```

*version_number* being the kernel version you want to remove, usually, you would want at least two versions on your hard drive in case you run into problems with the newer updated kernel version.

```
/etc/default/grub
```

This file contains basic settings which would be considered normal for the user to configure. Options include the time the menu is displayed, the default OS to boot, etc. The entries in this file can be edited by a user with administrator (root) privileges and are incorporated into grub.cfg when it is updated. The default options included in file upon installation are only a small number of the variables which GRUB 2 can recognize.

While the most common settings are present in the default file, additional environmental settings are available for inclusion in this file. These include items such as backgrounds and themes. The pre-defined variables are contained in `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` and can be listed using the following command:

```
grep "export GRUB_DEFAULT" -A50 /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig | grep GRUB_
```

After making changes to the file you must run this command to make the changes permanent:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I gave grub-customizer a try before posting the question and couldn't find any way to delete a grub installation using it... I couldn't even find the faulty grub install when trying to change environments. It only suggests partitions (nvme0n1p1 to p5 while I believe the faulty grub is at the "root" of the disk, nvme0n1, if that makes any sense)

Comment: have you looked in /etc/grub.d, or /etc/default/grub to see if the duplicate entry is listed in there?

Comment: What should I be looking for in either of these folders? Just in case, as I don't know if that was clear, the issue is not an extra entry in grub (the one I'm using is properly set up), but a whole separate grub installation in another location of the disk that shows up in the motherboard's boot menu.

Comment: Checkout the link I added in the above answer this should help you solve your issue

Comment: Also, the nvme0n1 is probably a disk connected through an NVM Express port instead of e.g. a traditional SATA port. So you /dev/nvme0n1 is probably equivalent to /dev/sda1 if that helps any

Comment: Thank you for the link, but as I feared this is to fix the entries in grub, what I'm trying to do is remove an extra installation of grub itself, not the entries it shows